# Determine whether $F(x)= 5x+10$ is $O(x^2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Please, can someone here help me to understand the Big-O notation in discrete mathematics?

> Determine whether $F(x)= 5x+10$ is $O(x^2)$

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o
This thread contains some of the best explanations for a beginner.

Comment: can you answer this pertaining to my problem

Comment: I guess it is not,because you see 5x+10 is linear.So the function of x increases in a linear way corresponding to x.Hence it is O(x).

Comment: @vaidy_mit Actually, that's not true.  Big-O gives only an _upper bound_ - so, being $O(x)$ automatically makes you $O(x^2)$ as well (given that $x\rightarrow\infty$).  What you describe is actually $\Theta$- (that is, Big-Theta) notation.

Comment: @ nrpeterson Thanks sir !! @ user83632 sorry for directing you in a wrong way !! And yeah,big O can be  otherwise called as worst case complexity,and hence it can be O(x2) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us give a definition for Big-O notation:

Suppose $g(x)\geq 0$.  We say that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ if:

*Loosely*: $\lvert f(x)\rvert$ is bounded by a constant multiple of $g(x)$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

*Rigorously*: There exists $C>0$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x>X$, we have $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq Cg(x)$.

In your case, we deal with $f(x)=5x+10$. So, we want to show that for $x$ sufficiently large, $f(x)$ can be bounded by $Cx^2$ for some $C$.

To make life simple, let's assume $x\geq 10$, so that $\lvert 5x+10\rvert=5x+10\leq 5x+x=6x$. Now, if $x\geq 10$, then $x\leq x^2$.  So, for $x\geq 10$, we have
$$
\lvert 5x+10\rvert=5x+10\leq 6x\leq 6x^2.
$$
Hence it is true that $5x+10=O(x^2)$, as you were asked.

The big idea with Big-O notation is this: all it asks you to do is to think about the *rate of growth* of the function, once $x$ is large enough that only leading terms really matter.  In this case, the exact order of your function is $x$; for $x\rightarrow\infty$, of course $x^2$ is a faster rate of growth than $x$ is.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214648/big-o-problem). You can use the fact

> $$f=O(g)\quad \rm{iff} \quad \limsup_{x \to \infty}\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} =c,$$

where $c$ is finite.

Comment: Isn't this usually stated using $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$? For example, consider $x|\sin x| = O(x)$, for which the limit does not exist but the limit superior does.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams: [See here](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/big-O.pdf).

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Downvoter: So it is not a wrong answer. What's the down vote for?

Comment: @nrpeterson: It is iff.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Downvote removed.  Sorry to be a stickler!

Answer (score 1):

It is as $x \to \infty$.
Actually, $5x+10 = o(x^2)$ as $x \to \infty$
(little-oh)
since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5x+10}{x^2} = 0$.

However,
$5x+10 \ne O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$,
and  $5x \ne O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$,
because
there is no real $c$ such that
$5x < c x^2$ as $x \to 0$.

Since $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$ are the two common
limits for big-oh notation,
it is important to state which one is meant.

Comment: +1 for using $o(x)$, which is in my opinion more appropriate for this case

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
Yes, it is $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$.

Long answer:
Let's look at the definition of $\mathcal{O}$:

> $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ if and only if there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such that:
>   $$|f(x)| \le M|g(x)| \text{ for all } x \gt x_0$$

In layman's terms, this is saying that $\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ is an *upper bound* to the function.  Basically, at some point, $g(x)$ grows as fast or faster than $f(x)$.

Clearly, $x^2$ eventually beats out $x$ in terms of growth over the long haul.  In the "long haul," (as $x \to \infty$), it doesn't matter what is added to $x$ or what $x$ is multiplied by--$x^2$ will beat it.  Thus, $x^2$ is an upper bound.

(This is a non-rigorous argument, of course.  Rather than prove it for you, this is just meant to give a feel for how $\mathcal{O}$ works.)