# Numerical Analysis and Big O

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

How can I show that $e^x -1$ is not $O(x^2)$ as $x\to0$

I'm not sure where to start. We can use Taylor's Theorem with remainder:

\begin{equation}
e^x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{x^n}{n!} +\dfrac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
\end{equation}

Where $\infty < x < \infty$ and $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$. However, when and why would you cut off at $n=1$? Also, what is the significance that $x\to0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying $e^x-1=_0O(x^2)$ is similar to say that the function $x\mapsto\frac{e^x-1}{x^2}$ is bounded as $x$ tend to $0$ which isn't the case since 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x^2}=\infty$$

Comment: It's true that $\frac{e^x - 1}{x^2}$ is unbounded as $x \to 0$, but the expression you wrote isn't quite correct since $\lim_{x \to 0^+} = +\infty$, while $\lim_{x \to 0^-} = - \infty$.

Comment: I don't precise the sign of $\infty$ since it does not concern me in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The power series is probably the best general approach. However, if you know that the derivative of $e^x$ at $0$ is $1$, you can use the definition of the derivative to conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1,$$ which does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427971/determine-whether-fx-5x10-is-ox2/427983#427983).

**Hint:**

> $f=O(g)$ iff $\limsup_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=c$,

where $c$ is finite.

**Added:** In your case the limit goes to infinity which implies that $e^x-1$ is not a big O of $x^2$.