# I feel very stupid. Will someone walk me through a step-by-step in plain english of this Big-O problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Prove that $n^2 + 2n + 3$ is $O(n^2)$.  Find values for $C$ and $k$ that prove that they work.

Edit:  In particular, I don't at all understand how to find C and k.

I asked a similar question but every response went way over my head.  The similar question is linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437098/big-o-notation-prove-that-n2-2n-3-is-mathcal-on2).   Sorry, I guess I'm not that smart!

Comment: You should ask for clarification, not ask the question again.

Comment: If you tell yourself something enough times, you may start to believe it. Everyone has what they feel are stupid questions, but what is more stupid is when one will not ask them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to give you a lengthy discussion of what $\mathcal O$ means. (All functions here are assumed non-negative, and their domains are the positive integers.)

You say $f = \mathcal O(g)$ if there exists $C > 0$ and $k > 0$ such that $Cg(n) > f(n)$ for all $n > k$.

Let's first investigate this definition when $C$ is not allowed to be chosen arbitrarily, but fixed at $1$.

$$
f = \mathcal O(g) \text{ if there exists } k > 0 \text{ such that } g(n) > f(n) \text{ for all } n > k.
$$

This means that $g$ **eventually** dominates $f$.

For example, intuitively $n^2$ eventually dominates $2n$. (You can see this by plotting with Wolfram Alpha.) But you do have to prove formally that $n^2 > 2n$ actually holds when $n$ is *big enough*. By plugging in the first few test numbers, you can see that $3^2 > 2\cdot 3$, and $n^2$ continues to grow faster than $2n$ when $n > 2$. This gives you $k = 2$. Note, however, that you could also pick $k$ anything larger than $2$.

[I did skip one step when I claimed that $n^2$ continues to grow faster than $2n$ when $n > 2$. This can be proved by looking at the increment of each function as $n$ increases. Going from $n$ to $n + 1$, the first function increases by $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n + 1$, while the second function increases by $2(n+1) - 2n = 2$. This means $n^2$ will grow faster than $2n$ when $2n + 1 > 2$, *i.e.*, $n > \frac 12$. Since we pick $k = 2$, our claim above is valid.]

Next, we come to the discussion of $C$. The big O notation is intended to quantify the "degree of growth", so if we have a function, say $n^6$, we want to say that $n^6$, $2n^6$, $10n^6$ and so on all grow at the same degree. That is where $C$ comes into play.

Let me take the opportunity here to say that we could relax strict inequalities ($>$) in the definition of $\mathcal O$ to non-strict ones ($\ge$) without changing anything.

In the example you gave, $n^2 + 2n + 3$ is a sum of three terms: $n^2$, $2n$, and $3$. With the non-strict definition

- $n^2$ (in fact any function) dominates itself for $C = 1$ and any $k$, so we can even pick $k = 0$
- $n^2$ dominates $2n$ for $C = 1$ and $k = 2$
- $n^2$ dominates $3$ for $C = 1$ and $k = 2$

Now you combine all these dominations into one by adding up $C$'s and taking the maximum of $k$'s. This can be written more formally as

For $n \ge 2$,
\begin{align*}
n^2 & \ge n^2 \\
n^2 & \ge 2n \\
n^2 & \ge 3 \\
\therefore 3n^2 & \ge n^2 + 2n + 3.
\end{align*}

To conclude, the sentence
$$
n \ge 2 \text{ implies } 3n^2 \ge n^2 + 2n + 3
$$
demonstrates $n^2 + 2n + 3 = \mathcal O(n^2)$ with $k = 2$ and $C = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

We have a polynomial $P(n)=n^2+2n+3$. Now, we want to find some constant $C$ and $k$ such that $P(n)\leq Cn^2$ for any $n\geq k$. We note that we can break the polynomial up in its different pieces, and if we make each piece $O(n^2)$, we would have made the whole polynomial $O(n^2)$. Let's start with the easy case: when is $$3\leq n^2$$ true? Well, $n=1$ fails, but $n=2$ doesn't, and we know $n^2$ will keep on growing. So we know $3$ is $O(n^2)$ with $C_1=1$, $k_1=2$. Now, look at $2n$. Then $n\leq n^2$ is true for any $n\geq 1$. So we find $2n$ is $O(n^2)$ with $C_2=2\times 1$ and $k_2=1$. Finally, $n^2$ is $O(n^2)$ since $n^2\leq n^2$ is always true, so $C_3=1$, $k_3=1$.

Finally, we take $C=C_1+C_2+C_3$ and $k_0=\max\{k_1,k_2,k_3\}$, and we are done: $P(n)$ is $O(n^2)$ with constant $C=1+2+1=4$ and $k=k_0=2$. I invite you to think about this last step.

Comment: Why did you choose $2$?  How did you come to choose $2$?  Why did you make up the equation $n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2 = 4n^2$?  Thank you for your answer, but I asked for a plain English walk-through/explanation, and I still don't understand your answer.

Comment: Why did you choose to state the inequality $3 \le n^2$?  Why is this important?

Comment: @discretemath Maybe now it is clearer?

Comment: So I just break the polynomial into its individual pieces, and find values for $C$ and $k$ for each piece, then sum the coefficients for $C$ of the entire polynomial?  For $k$, I just find the highest value of $k$ for each term, which was $k_1 = 2$ when determining $k$ for $3$?

Comment: @discretemath Yes.

Comment: Err... what is that? @discretemath Remember you want $f(n)\leq Cg(n)$ to hold for **any** $n\geq k$, for some $k$ (for example $k=12$), not only when $n=k$.

Comment: [link]http://i.imgur.com/g9G7hi9.png    Isn't that what I'm showing?  That $f(x) \le 3g(n)$ when $n \ge 2$?

Comment: You have "when $n=2$", but it should read "when $n\geq 2$".

Comment: Oh!  Thank you.   Also, would you be able to help me with $\Omega$ notation?  For example: show that $n^2 - 2n - 3$ is $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: @discretemath You should make that into a new post. The idea is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

We want to bound everything by a multiple of $n^2$. Notice that $$(3,2n,n^2)=(3,2,1), (3, 4, 4), (3, 6, 9), \cdots$$

You can see that $n^2$ bounds the other terms from above from the second term onwards, so you might as well take $n\ge 2$. If you prefer take $n\ge 100$ just to make sure.

Then the sum is at most $n^2 + n^2 + n^2$ from this point on, so $3n^2$ would do. Or $100n^2$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If $n\ge 1$, then $2n\le 2n^2$.

If $n \ge 1$, then $3 \le 3n^2$.

So if $n \ge 1$, then 
$$n^2+2n+3\le n^2+2n^2+3n^2=6n^2.$$

Thus in the language of your question, we can take $C=6$ and $k=1$.