# Why does this function decrease at this speed?

Tags: complex-analysis

As a part of a problem I am using this:

I know that $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges absolutely in a region around zero, offcourse its value at zero is zero. I also know that it is is continuous.

But I need to show that as z goes to zero I have:

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_kz^k\right|\le C\cdot|z^{n+1}|$$

I mean on the left side I have:

$|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_kz^k|=|a_{n+1}\cdot z^{n+1}+\sum_{k=n+2}^\infty a_kz^k|$. I really feel that there is some simple or smart trick to just show that we can pick a C that covers the last part of the sum. But I have no idea of how to find it. Can someone please think of a trick here?

Comment: If you denote the function by $f$, what is $$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,?$$

Comment: Please don't use the asterisk $*$ for multiplication (outside of programming). In mathematics, it stands for convolution, which is a different sort of beast. I replaced it with a dot (`\cdot`).

Comment: @DanielFischer I get $\Sigma_{i=n+1}^{\infty}a_k*z^{i-n-1}$. I see what you mean. This is probably a very stupid question, but how do we know it converges to zero? It probably is obvious, but I can't use l'hopital. Is this argument correct?: g is continuos at all points around zero, because it is created by two continuous functions. If we look at the expression for g it is zero at zero. [But I can't really finish because I dont see how to force g to converge to zero.]

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thank you, I will try to remember that!

Comment: Is this the tail of a power series of an analytic function?

Comment: The series for $g$ converges in the same disk as the series for $f$ [the convergence in boundary points of the disk may differ, but we're not interested in that]. The sum of a convergent power series is a continuous function on its disk of convergence. Thus we have $g(0) = a_{n+1}$, and $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert a_{n+1}\rvert + 1$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yeah, but how do we know it is analytic after the division? I mean, we divided on something and that may mess things up because what we divided on is not defined at zero? I mean after we look at the expression we see that at zero it is zero, but I don't see how convergence to zero is guranteed?

Comment: @DanielFischer Do we use that in the new series $1/R=lim sup |a_n|^{1/n}$ doesnt change? I mean technically it could change because the new $a_1$ doesnt correspond to the original n=1. But we can prove it is the same either way?

Comment: What you seem to be missing is that the exponent $i-n-1$ is *nonnegative* in all terms of the new series. No nasty denominators to worry about, it's just a power series.

Comment: Basically what I mean is I have to prove that $lim sup |a_{i+n+1}|^{1/i}=lim sup|a_i|^{1/i}$?

Comment: That's one way to see that the two series have the same radius of convergence. Another way is to use that fact that the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k$ has radius of convergence $\geqslant r$ if and only if $a_k\cdot r^k$ is a bounded sequence.

Comment: @user119615: See my answer.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I understand that, the problem is that we have a completely new powerseries, so we do not even know if it converges I think, I mean it is not just the tail of a power series that we know converges, we have change it by mixing the correspening indexes in the $a_n$ and exponent? But I see it will follow from the lim sup argument, or with what Daniel Fisher said about r(I dont see why that is equivalent with the lim sup argument, so I would have to prove that first). So we have to do the limsup argument?, it seems very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to prove the following

> $$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_kz^k = O(z^{n+1}), \quad z\to 0.  $$

Here is a useful result you can use

> If $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = b $ then $f(z)=O(g(z)) $ or $|f(z)|\leq M |g(z)|$,

where $b$ is finite. See the [main result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427971/determine-whether-fx-5x10-is-ox2).